# Python Dataframe Looping Operations Efficiency

Tags: python, pandas, performance, loops, dataframe

I have two pieces of input, a dataframe containing stock on hand for all products and a list of dataframes where each dataframe contains orders for multiple products. The orders dataframes can contain multiple orders for the same product and the orders can be greater than the available stock on hand.

## Sample input data:

### List of dataframes containing orders

```
[    prodID    orderQTY
 0   ABC1      456
 1   ABC2      703
 2   ABC3      359
 3   ABC4      492
 4   ABC5      824
 ..  ...       ...
 [100 rows x 2 columns],
     prodID    orderQTY
 0   ABC10     805
 1   ABC11     860
 2   ABC12     651
 3   ABC13     662
 4   ABC14     802
 ..  ...       ...
 [100 rows x 2 columns],
     prodID    orderQTY
 0   ABC100    111
 1   ABC101    834
 2   ABC102    302
 3   ABC103    386
 4   ABC104    318
 ..  ...       ...
 [100 rows x 2 columns]]
```

### Dataframe with stock on hand

```
    prodID    onHand
0   ABC1      37200
1   ABC2      38945
2   ABC3      38085
3   ABC4      43775
4   ABC5      10999
..  ...       ...
 [300 rows x 2 columns]
```

I've written a function to iterate through the orders within each dataframe within the list and update the available stock on hand. The function will then output a dataframe with all of the orders that shows the beginning inventory, order amount, and ending inventory.

## Function:

```
def fulfill_orders(order_list, stock):
# create empty dataframe where the results will go
combined = pd.DataFrame(columns=['prodID', 'startSTOCK', 'orderQTY', 'endSTOCK'])

# loop through dataframes in order_list
for orders in order_list:
    # create unique list of product ids
    ids = orders['prodID'].unique()
    # loop through unique list of product ids
    for id in ids:
        # create dataframe that consists of a single product id
        df = orders.groupby('prodID').get_group(id)
        # merge stock on hand onto single product id dataframe
        df = df.merge(stock, how='left', on='prodID')
        # rename stock on hand column
        df.rename(columns={'onHAND': 'startSTOCK'}, inplace=True)
        # create ending stock column and calculate value for first row
        df.loc[0,'endSTOCK'] = df.loc[0, 'startSTOCK'] - df.loc[0, 'orderQTY']
        # check if ending stock for first row is less than zero
        if df.loc[0, 'endSTOCK'] < 0:
            # reset negative first row ending stock to starting stock
            df.loc[0, 'endSTOCK'] = df.loc[0, 'startSTOCK']
        # loop through remaining rows
        for i in range(1, len(df)):
            # set starting stock to previous ending stock
            df.loc[i, 'startSTOCK'] = df.loc[i-1, 'endSTOCK']
            # calculate new ending stock
            df.loc[i, 'endSTOCK'] = df.loc[i, 'startSTOCK'] - df.loc[i, 'orderQTY']
            # check if ending stock is less than zero
            if df.loc[i, 'endSTOCK'] < 0:
                # reset negative ending stock to starting stock
                df.loc[i, 'endSTOCK'] = df.loc[i, 'startSTOCK']
        # append results to output dataframe
        combined = combined.append(df, ignore_index=True)
        # remove extra columns
        df = df[['prodID', 'endSTOCK']]
        # rename columns
        df.rename(columns={'endSTOCK': 'onHAND'}, inplace=True)
        # keep only last value
        df = df.iloc[[-1]]
        # update the stock on hand dataframe
        stock = pd.concat([stock, df]).drop_duplicates(['prodID'], keep='last')

# change column types to integer
combined['startSTOCK'] = combined.startSTOCK.astype(int)
combined['endSTOCK'] = combined.endSTOCK.astype(int)

# reorder columns
combined = combined[['prodID', 'startSTOCK', 'orderQTY', 'endSTOCK']]

# reset index
combined.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# drop orders not fulfilled
combined.drop(combined[(combined.startSTOCK <= 0) | (combined.orderQTY > combined.startSTOCK)].index, inplace=True)

# reset index
combined.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

return combined.sort_values(['prodID', 'startSTOCK'], ascending=[True, False])
```

## Sample output:

```
    prodID    startSTOCK    orderQTY    endSTOCK
0   ABC1      37200         456         36744
1   ABC2      38945         703         38242
2   ABC3      38085         359         37726
3   ABC4      43775         492         43283
4   ABC5      10999         824         10175
..  ...       ...           ...         ...
[300 rows x 4 columns]
```

My concern is that this function may be inefficient on larger input data. Is there a more efficient way to achieve my desired outcome?

Comment: When you post questions like this, please post a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df_order
```

outputs

```
  prodID  orderQTY
0   ABC1       456
1   ABC2       703
2   ABC3       359
3   ABC4       492
4   ABC5       824
```

It took the list of DataFrames (`dfs`) to be the first part of the first DataFrame you showed repeated three times.

```
dfs = [df_order] * 3
df_stock = df_stock.set_index('prodID')
```

**Process**

```
df_orders = pd.concat(dfs).groupby('prodID').sum()
df_all = df_stock.join(df_orders)
df_all['endSTOCK'] = df_all['onHand'] - df_all['orderQTY']
df_all
```

returns

```
        onHand  orderQTY  endSTOCK
prodID
ABC1     37200      1368     35832
ABC2     38945      2109     36836
ABC3     38085      1077     37008
ABC4     43775      1476     42299
ABC5     10999      2472      8527
```